# How to change some of the code of a Java program?

Tags: java

Note: I'm only a student and don't have too much experience with programming, so please be patient with me.

I'm trying to modify the code of an existing program written in Java, so that the program runs exactly as normal except for my couple changes.

I found and unzipped the appropriate jar file and put the `.class` I want through a decompiler. But, after modifying the code, I can't re-compile it. The javac compiler just gives me a bunch of errors, mostly because it doesn't recognize the references to variables and methods that are defined in different classes of the program.

How can I change a couple lines of code in a Java program? Am I on the right track with my current approach (decompile→edit→recompile)?

SOLUTION: I had to include the classpath of the jar. `javac -cp "[PATH TO JAR]:lib/*" [PATH TO JAVA FILE]`

Comment: We would need some more context.  Please share the exact error stack trace and the code that is causing problem.

Comment: @shmosel I've read the "duplicate" question. Does this mean I need to decompile every single class file in the program and recompile them?

Comment: No, but that's an option.